# scheduled execution of a function every 20 mins

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to run a function scheduled execution every 20 minutes when the application is running.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms, WPF, or other type of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you created a timer?

You set the property `enabled` to true, set the interval to `72000000` (which is 20 min in ms).

Then, in your code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object,ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
 // Put here the code portion you want
End Sub
```